# Show successful pattern as result

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching

I'm doing pattern match like this:

```
SELECT     ea.Text
    FROM         dbo.Parameters AS n INNER JOIN
                          dbo.Descriptions AS ea ON ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + n.par2 + n.Achtervoegsel + '%' OR 
                          ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + '_' + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3 + '%' OR 
                          ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3 + '%' OR ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + '_' + n.par2 + n.par3 + '%' OR 
                          ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + '__' + n.par2 + n.par3 + '%' OR 
                          ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + '__' + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3 + '%'
```

Well, this works fine. The six possible patterns are being matched.
But now my question.

I would like to add an output column showing me the succesful pattern.
For example if my ea.Text is:

**THIS IS A LONG DESCRIPTION WITH APPLE 2000-A AND OTHER THINGS**

and my table with the parameters has a record with
par1 'APPLE'
par2 '2000'
par3 'A'

Then this pattern will give a result:

```
'%' + n.par1 + '_' + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3 + '%'
```

In this case, I would like to have a column that says

APPLE 2000-A

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that an 'OR' is behind the scenes than the reworked query with unions you can do something like this:

```
SELECT ea.Text, n.par1 + n.par2 + n.Achtervoegsel
FROM dbo.Parameters AS n 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Descriptions AS ea ON ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + n.par2 + n.Achtervoegsel + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ea.Text, n.par1 + '_' + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3
FROM dbo.Parameters AS n 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Descriptions AS ea ON ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + '_' + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3 + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ea.Text, n.par1 + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3
FROM dbo.Parameters AS n 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Descriptions AS ea ON ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3 + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ea.Text, n.par1 + '_' + n.par2 + n.par3
FROM dbo.Parameters AS n 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Descriptions AS ea ON ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + '_' + n.par2 + n.par3 + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ea.Text, n.par1 + '__' + n.par2 + n.par3
FROM dbo.Parameters AS n 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Descriptions AS ea ON ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + '__' + n.par2 + n.par3 + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ea.Text, n.par1 + '__' + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3
FROM dbo.Parameters AS n 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Descriptions AS ea ON ea.Text LIKE '%' + n.par1 + '__' + n.par2 + '_' + n.par3 + '%'
```

If you really want the exact values that were matched against (and not the '_'-s) you might want to look into the substring() function. I don't know any other solutions for that particular problem.

Comment: If you want the values matched you might want to look into the functions substring(), charindex(), patindex(). These could help you get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a function, a pretty good way of doing this would be to do the matching there, and return the search string you found!  You could then easily return the matching string as a column:

**The Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MatchingString
(
    @text nvarchar(100),
    @par1 nvarchar(100),
    @par2 nvarchar(100),
    @par3 nvarchar(100)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @searchString nvarchar(100);
    declare @currSearchString nvarchar(100);
    declare @charIndex int = -1;

    set @currSearchString = Concat(@par1,'_',@par2,'_',@par3);
    set @charIndex = CharIndex(@searchString,@text,0);

    if(@charIndex >= 0) begin
        set @searchString = @currSearchString;
    end

    --loop over more searchstrings or do it manually


    return @searchString;
END
```

**The Query**

```
    SELECT     ea.Text,
MatchingString = dbo.MatchingString(ea.Text,n.par1,n.par2,n.par3)
    FROM         dbo.Parameters AS n INNER JOIN
        dbo.Descriptions AS ea ON dbo.MatchingString(ea.Text,n.par1,n.par2,n.par3) IS NOT NULL
```